# True Kiosk Mode

Tags: ubuntu-mate, kiosk

I am trying to run Ubuntu Mate as a kiosk. I can get the chromium to go into kiosk at login but I can still access the launcher with shortcuts and other shortcuts using the keyboard. How can I make it lock to only one application and remove access to anything else?

Comment: Why do you need a desktop environment if you only want to run chromium in kiosk mode? Please [edit] your question and explain your use case in more detail.

Comment: I still need to be able to access MATE for admin purposes. I am basically making a NVR with Zoneminder.

Comment: That still doesn't explain why you need to run the kiosk on MATE. Instead of trying to make the DE look and feel like there is no DE, it would be a lot easier to omit it in the first place.

Comment: Well I need one user to have no DE and and the other admin account to have a DE.

Comment: If your intent is to prevent accidental user errors, openbox would probably be better suited for the kiosk session. If you want to make a secure kiosk, there is a tutorial on ubuntu.com: [secure kiosk tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/secure-ubuntu-kiosk#1-overview). I doubt that you will be able to make a secure kiosk with MATE, as that's probably not a use case the developers had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

As was suggested in comments (I can't post those) - your solution is to have two users, and allow the one that's used for kiosk to only use openbox.

When openbox is installed it will show up as another option on login.

From there, depending on your further needs, either present login screen for a few seconds, then automatically login to kiosk user (which starts openbox-session and then chromium --kiosk), or just wait at login screen. I assume first option would be prefered.

If you want to manage it, use those few seconds to select the Admin user.

One more thing, and it circumvents your dual login and Mate and all. Why not just enable OpenSSH, and use SSH to manage the kiosk? The process is pretty much same, have a limited "kiosk" user, auto-login to this user, start fullscreen Chromium. And when you SSH use your "administrator". Usually there's not much need to "manage" kiosk, except change default homepage (which is somewhere in a script anyway), or make updates (that's done easily with cli/SSH, or even setup as automatic task)